# How do u prove $\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{2^{k}}\binom{n+k}{n} = 2^{n}$?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, generating-functions

Here is the expression

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{2^{k}}\binom{n+k}{n} = 2^{n}$$

How to go about proving this? I tried expanding the expression and it seems that $n+1$ must be even. But it isn't helping much. Can someone please help? Can this be proved using generating functions or combinatorics?

Comment: Yes,Thank you. I couldn't find it on my own. Should I delete my question now or let it remain?

Comment: I believe either option is fine. I found this with Approach0 (https://approach0.xyz/search/), and it has proven to be quite powerful.

Comment: WOW!!. I am gonna let my question be here. Someone like me in the future will surely want to know the link u gave.Thanks man!!!